# webpart is not detecting language change

Tags: multilingual, master-pages, web-parts, product-variations, sharepoint-2019

in our sharepoint website we have page include webpart . site is using 2 language english and arabic IF im login as Anonymous Users: when change from englsh to arabic client side code detect not detect webpart language and display the page in arabic but webpart still showing in english

BUT if I'm login as sharepoint admin: it is working and detect the language and change webpart language

what can be the issue here ?

machine translated is off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I completely understand your question or the type of webpart that you are using, and I don't know how you are changing your language, and I don't know whether you are using Variations, but there are several factors that can determine the language of your SharePoint 2019 user interface and the language of content.  If your user profile has a preferred display language that matches one of the site languages, and the user profile has turned on the setting to override the site settings, then that is what is used.  If not, then the browser's language setting is used.  If not, then the site base language is used.  Anonymous users do not have user profiles.  Read-only users do not always have the right to change their own language preference in their profile.  In addition, changing the language in your profile does not have an immediate effect unless you have a 3rd party app to make it change immediately.  It can take several minute to update to the new language, and in some cases up to a day.

Comment: we used sharepoint as publics website for our company
Variations yes it is used
machine translate is disable
to make sharepoint open for public as website on internet we give Anonymous user access